# Are Skylanders figures compatible with all platforms?

Tags: skylanders

Does anybody know whether Skylanders bought for PS3 will work on other platforms as well? Or are Skylanders platform specific?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the **Wii, Wii U, PS3, and PS4 Portals** are all **interchangeable**. It is only the **Xbox 360 and Xbox One Portals** that are **console specific**. If you're still confused though, take a look at the compatibility charts in the link below.

https://skylanderscharacterlist.com/getting-started/portal-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already gotten an answer, but I figured for those looking at this way late (myself a year behind the curve apparently) that I'd share this link:
https://skylanderscharacterlist.com/getting-started/figure-compatibility/
It looks like the characters can be used on all platforms, portals are a different story.

Comment: Could you [edit] in some relevant information from the link in case it dies?